# Abbreviation (abbr) element in reStructuredText

Tags: restructuredtext

How to generate an [`<abbr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/abbr) abbreviation element in ReST?

`<abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr>`

The [documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/doctree.html#abbreviation) indicates that "The abbreviation element is not exposed in default restructured text. It can only be accessed through custom roles." I'm not sure how to create such a custom role, and [the](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#custom-interpreted-text-roles) [rest](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/roles.html) [of](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#interpreted-text) [the](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/howto/rst-roles.html) documentation is a tad obscure to me.

Comment: The `abbreviation` role you mention worked for me (as `\`HTML\`:abbreviation:`), albeit through Sphinx rather than vanilla Docutils. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to add the `title` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it for now by adding this at the bottom of the document:

```
.. |HTMLabbr| raw:: html

  <abbr title="Hypertext Markup Language">HTML</abbr>
```

Then in the document I've used this "tag"/custom role like this:

```
This document is written in |HTMLabbr| and renders nicely in a modern browser.
```

For each abbreviation you would have to define a new custom role, I'm wondering if there is a way to have a "tag" that would take the value and the title as parameters instead of having to hard-code it like this.

Comment: Yes, such tag could be implemented via custom rst role so that one could write `:abbr:\`HTML\`` or `:abbr:\`WHATEVER\`` instead.

Answer (score 8):

For Sphinx users, an abbreviation can be added using the `:abbr:` role. For example,

```
This :abbr:`SDP (Software Development Plan)` defines ...
```

results in the following HTML

```
<p>This <abbr title="Software Development Plan">SDP</abbr> defines …</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom docutils rst role is not hard (compared to other ways how to extension docutils). See [rst roles howto](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/howto/rst-roles.html), which contains all the details along with a full implementation of example RFC role. I was able to create custom [bugzilla referencing role](https://github.com/mbukatov/pylatest/blob/master/pylatest/roles.py) based on this document.